# Log4j2 Root Location - Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j2

In log4j2.xml, root level includeLocation property is set to true, but when clicking the hyperlink in the console "Source not found for [36muitap.framework.DefaultSettings" is displayed.

Here part of the Appenders and Loggers

```
...
  <Console name="CONS" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}" disableAnsi="false"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONS" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In Console, location hyperlink is displayed
`2023-07-12 10:22:40.957 [ DEBUG] [main] - [uitap.utils.ZSettings(ZSettings.java:106)   : hrties(real.user)`

But the **(ZSettings.java:106)** hyperlinks throws "Source not found...".

Additional details: I just noticed that when the log file displays logs like this:

```
2023-07-12 10:22:40.957 [ [36mDEBUG[m] [[35mmain[m] -  [36muitap.utils.ZSettings[m(ZSettings.java:86)  : hrties(real.user)
2023-07-12 10:22:40.957 [ [36mDEBUG[m] [[35mmain[m] -  [36muitap.utils.ZSettings[m(ZSettings.java:86)  : hrties(foreign.user)
2023-07-12 10:22:40.957 [ [36mDEBUG[m] [[35mmain[m] -  [36muitap.utils.ZSettings[m(ZSettings.java:86)  : hrties(local.user)
```

Souldn't the count starts in ... [34m ... [35m ... [36m...?

I remember moving some maven packages around using "refactor" feature, so I would like that fact as the cause of the number order issue.

Any pointing direction is welcome, thanks.

**What did I try?**

1. I tried changing folder changing package order using Java Build Path >> Order and Export
2. I tried verify that all classes properly have the Logger log = LogManager.getLogger() with the class parameter.

Comment: The `[36m` stuff is just attempts to set the console colours using `ANSI control codes`. You can enable support for colours in the Eclipse console in the Eclipse Preferences in 'Run/Debug > Console > ANSI Support'

Comment: @greg-449, then it does not have anything to do with "Source not found..." existing issue. Thanks.